# NetTopologySuite: calculate length/area of geography

Tags: geospatial, nettopologysuite, dbgeography

I've been using DbGeography in C# to calculate length and area of WKT geometries (geographies), like this:

```
var polygon = DbGeography.FromText(wkt, 4326);
var area = polygon.Area;
var line = DbGeography.FromText(wkt2, 4326);
var length = line.Lenght;
```

How can I achieve this using NetTopologySuite? My WKTs represent lat/longs in degrees.
Are there any existing implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possbile to convert from WKT to Geometry data types using the `WKTReader` and is explained in the Documentation here: [Link](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/wiki/GettingStarted#well-known-text)

An example of how to use it would be:

```
public class GeographyHelper
{
    private static GeometryFactory _geometryFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326);
        }
    }

    public void CheckArea()
    {
        var wellKnownTextPoly = "YOUR POLYGON WKT";
        var wellKnownTextLine = "YOUR LINE WKT";

        var rdr = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader();
        var geometry = rdr.Read(wellKnownTextPoly);

        var polygon = _geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(geometry.Coordinates);
        var area = polygon.Area;

        var lineGeometry = rdr.Read(wellKnownTextLine);
        var line = _geometryFactory.CreateLineString(lineGeometry.Coordinates);
        var length = line.Length;
    }
}
```